# Reducing the execution time of the code using ICC compiler

Tags: performance, gcc

I am working on certain DSP based algorithms which involve massive computation. I have used the gcc library with all the options (-O3, -ftreevectorize...). The execution time of the whole code is 43 ms. I run the same code using the ICC compiler but there is no significant reduction in the execution time of the code. How can I reduce my code execution time in ICC without modifying the existing code? (without using SIMD/S and asm)

Comment: What flags are you passing to ICC ? Also what CPU are you running this on ? You might want to consider profiling your code to see where the hotspots are and to determine whether you are compute-bound or memory-bound.

Comment: @Paul: Right. I've seen code like this (and written some) where a simple call to `exp`, `log` , `pow`, or `sqrt`, was dominant. Simply memoizing it made a huge difference.

Comment: Im passing icc -03 -axSSE4.1  file.c

Answer (score 0):

If your requirements for floating-point math are not stringent, the easiest optimization will come from `icc -fast file.c`

However, this will turn on `-no-prec-div` as well, which you might not want.  In that case, try passing `icc -O3 -axSSE4.1 -ipo file.c`

If you are willing to put a bit more time into compiling, you may be able to get substantial speed benefits from profiling.  `icc -O3 -axSSE4.1 -ipo -prof_gen file.c` will set you up to generate a profile.  Then run your code a few times, exercising the most common use case, and recompile using `icc -O3 -axSSE4.1 -ipo -prof_use file.c`

Comment: I have used all the flags mentioned by you.But there is no change

Comment: Unfortunately, that would indicate that the code, as written, cannot be statically optimized (e.g. by just examining the code without a running context).  However, the profiling option will help the compiler to determine most likely codepaths and re-arrange its output to optimize that.

Comment: Well...When i was searching for a good compiler I came across clang. This compiler gives me same result as other compilers like icc,pgi. But the problem is there are very few tutorials on this compiler...Kindly let me know where can i find the tutorials on the same.